# Uncaught ReferenceError: d3Scale is not defined ／ D3 V4 ／ rollup.js

Tags: d3.js, rollupjs

```
$ npm install d3-scale
$ npm install --save-dev rollup rollup-plugin-babel babel-preset-es2015-rollup
```

---

**I created the following file.**

▼src/scripts/main.js

```
import   { scaleLinear }   from   "d3-scale" ;
```

---

**I created the following file.**

▼rollup.config.js

```
// Rollup plugins
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  entry: 'src/scripts/main.js',
  dest: 'build/js/main.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  external: [ 'd3-scale' ],
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
  ],
};
```

---

```
$ npm run build
```

**The following file was created automatically**

▼build/js/main.min.js

```
(function (d3Scale) {
'use strict';



}(d3Scale));
```

---

**I created the following file.**

▼index.html

```
<script src="build/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

**An error occurred. Why?**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: d3Scale is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've specified `d3-scale` as an external module, if your bundle is included as a `<script>` tag then it needs to exist on the page already, and Rollup needs to know what the corresponding global variable is (which is `d3` — D3 is slightly unusual in that all the different packages are attached to the same namespace).

In other words, you need to do something like this...

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3"></script>
<script src="build/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

...and tell Rollup about `d3`:

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';

export default {
  entry: 'src/scripts/main.js',
  dest: 'build/js/main.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  external: [ 'd3-scale' ],
  globals: { 'd3-scale: 'd3' }, // <--- note this line
  plugins: [
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Alternatively, to include `d3-scale` and its dependencies in your bundle, use [rollup-plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-node-resolve).